# How to manipulate data in a MongoDB C# query?

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

I have my CITY collection as { id, name } and I need to find the correct city in a user-typed search. I've created a method in C# that cleans the typed string to search like:

User has typed: Órlândõ cítý
In Mongo: Orlando City

The method will clean and transform in ORLANDOCITY, but I need also transform the stored city in ORLANDOCITY string to find.

I've tried:

```
var stringCleaned = CleanToSearch(value);
_mongoCollection.Find(c => StringUtils.CleanToSearch(c.Name).Contains(stringCleaned)).ToList();
```

But i'm getting a Unsupported filter error. How I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure whats the difference is between the CleanToSearch and the StringUtils.CleanToSearch? I can see thet the later returns a collection but what is the purpose of the last method (StringUtils.CleanToSearch). I thought the purpose of CleanToSearch was to end up with the name of the city as it is stored in the database. Anyways, I'm not going to be one of those "Why do you do it like this" answers. 
You could always have a property in you City class containing the result of StringUtils.CleanToSearch (cityname). So when you create a new city you run the method and populate the property (CleanedNames).

```
public class City
{
    public City(string name)
    {
      Name = name;
      CleanedNames = StringUtils.CleanToSearch(name);
    }

    string Name {get; set;}
    string[] CleanedNames {get; set;}
}
```

The your search would be like:

```
 _mongoCollection.Find(c => c.CleanedNames.Contains(stringCleaned)).ToList();
```